# mv works interactively but not from script

Tags: bash, shell

I have been stuck on this issue the past four days now, and have tried modifying the code as much as possible to no avail.

The problem is my script's `mv` command has no effect. I tried replacing it with `cp`, which didn't change anything.

```
id="201910242020"
touch -t "$year$month$day$hr$min" /tmp/wakeup_$id.call
mv "/tmp/wakeup_$id.call" /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/
cat /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/wakeup_$id.call
```

Assume `$year$month$day$hr$min` is "201910242020"

If I take the **same exact line of code** from the script and paste it into the terminal, it works. The file gets moved.

When this runs as part of a script, all the lines execute except for the `mv`, which does not work for whatever reason, which subsequently causes the `cat` command to throw an error that the file doesn't exist. It doesn't exist, because it was never moved...

Why is this happening? I recreated the $id variable used in my script interactively and pasted the same line of code, and it worked interactively. I can't think why it would not when scripted.

When I add `set -x` and use the path to `mv` in my script, I get:

```
/home/com/noc.sh: line 832: /home/com/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
+ /usr/bin/mv -v /tmp/wakeup_5644201910251537.call /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/
/home/com/noc.sh: line 842: /usr/bin/mv: No such file or directory
```

Comment: A bunch of those variables are not defined, so please make a [mre]. (To start, if the timestamp is not important, just remove it entirely.) Also post the output of `type -a mv` from inside the script.

Comment: @wjandrea mv is /bin/mv

Comment: @wjandrea I don't know if the timestamp is important or not. I don't think it is, but I left it in to be safe

Comment: I notice that the `mv` command adds double quotes to the `/tmp/wakeup_$id.call`, but the `touch` command does not.  It may be worth making these two lines consistent. (It may also be worth removing the double quotes from where you've assigned to `id`)

Comment: @GregHNZ This was just the latest attempt. I previously had quotes around the touch input and it made no difference. I tried all possible combinations of quotes and not quotes. The $id variable does not actually appear like that in my script, but that is effectively what the variable looks like before that part of the script.

Comment: @InterLinked : That `mv` _silently_ refuses to work, simply does not happen. It would at least output an error message. Could it be that you have a shell function of the same name, which is shadowing /usr/bin/mv? I also would replace `mv` by `/usr/bin/mv -v`, and being paranoid, I would also run the script with `set -x` turned on.

Comment: @GregHNZ The quotes have no effect here, but generally in Bash you should prefer quoting to avoid word splitting and globbing.

Comment: @InterLinked Figure out whether the timestamp is important. If not, remove it. Also is `$id` important, or can you replace it with a static string?

Comment: @wjandrea ID is important. It prevents overwriting of calls files already in the dest. folder, so they don't get overwritten (so each ID is supposed to be unique). There is no warning from mv in the script, just from cat because the mv failed

Comment: @wjandrea Aha. `set -x` helped uncover the issue: Weird there was never any error about this: `
/bin/mv: cannot move '/tmp/wakeup_5644201910251540.call' to '/var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/wakeup_5644201910251540.call': Permission denied`